# RJ45 Female wall plate cat ratings

Tags: ethernet, layer1

I have CAT7 cables running trough the walls and I need to purchase wall plates. I am only finding wall plates rated for CAT6.

Does this really matter or are all RJ45 plugs/sockets the same?

Comment: Category-7 cabling is shielded, but Category-6 cabling is not, so mixing those parts renders the expensive Category-7 feature useless. ANSI/TIA/EIA 568 requires that a cabling plant not mix parts from one category to another. It also does not recognize Category-7, which is really ISO/IEC Class F. I would respectfully suggest that if you must ask this question, you really don't have the expertise to install it in a manner which would pass the ISO/IEC test suite for Class-F, and you have wasted a lot of money.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Cat7" (ANSI skipped it.) And I'd bet your cabling doesn't even meet Cat6 (6a) standards. (few people ever actually test for compliance; they point to the laser etched mark on the cable instead.)

Comment: Are you asking about actual wall plates or the female punchdown jacks that snap into them?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cat7 socket exists. http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-pcs-RJ45-8P8C-CAT-7-Modular-plug-ethernet-network-600MHz-connector-Shielded-/191813383260?hash=item2ca8f7f45c:g:4YsAAOSwx-9WzqLe

Cat7 required to make [10 Gigabit Ethernet over 100 m of copper cabling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11801#Category_7)
If You really need to achieve this, socket category and proper grounding is important.

[10GBASE-T, or IEEE 802.3an-2006 ... Category 6a is required to reach the full distance of 100 metres (330 ft) and category 6 may reach a distance of 55 metres (180 ft)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Gigabit_Ethernet#10GBASE-T)

For 1000BASE-T Cat5 is enough.

- Sometimes Cat6 used to keep Cat5 compatibility with sloppy
  installation.
- Wall socket much easier to replace when necessary, in compare to in-wall cabling.

It for what used higher that necessary now cables category.

Comment: Category-6a will do 10 Gbps (10GBASE-T) for 100 meters. This is a reason that ANSI/TIA/EIA has not, and seems that it will not, certified Category-7.

Comment: "over 100 meters" in context it look like more that 100. But not guarantee how more. Really look marketing. (I try make attention from standards to real usage)

Answer (score -1):

This depends on specific situations. Maybe the following links help you to better understand this question.
https://superuser.com/questions/663732/can-i-use-cat5e-jacks-with-cat6-cable
https://serverfault.com/questions/80014/is-there-a-difference-between-rj-45-plugs-for-cat-5e-and-cat-6

Comment: Please don't post link only answers (even to other stack exchange sites)